# How to solve this task using Topological sort?

Tags: topological-sort

There are N modules in the project. Each module has

(i) Completion time denoted in number of hours (Hi) and may depend on other modules. If Module x depends on Module y then one needs to complete y before x. s Project manager, you are asked to deliver the project as early as possible. Provide an estimation of amount of time required to complete the project.

Input Format:

First line contains T, number of test cases.

For each test case: First line contains N, number of modules. Next N lines, each contain: (i) Module ID (Hi) Number of hours it takes to complete the module (D) Set of module ids that i depends on - integers delimited by space.

Output Format:

Output the minimum number of hours required to deliver the project.

`Input: 1`

```
5  
1 5  
2 6 1  
3 3 2  
4 2 3  
5 1 3
```

`output: 16`

I know the problem is related to topological sorting.But cant get idea how to find total hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding Minimum Completion Time of Scheduled Tasks with Topological Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864641/finding-minimum-completion-time-of-scheduled-tasks-with-topological-sort)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the length of the [critical path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method). The is the *longest* path through the network from `start` to `finish` in the digraph where the nodes are the tasks, arrows from a node `A` to node `B` represent prerequisite relationships (`A` must be done before `B` begins) and the weight of an arrow is the time it takes to complete the source node task. If there isn't any well-defined `start` and `end` node it is common to create dummy nodes for that purpose. Create a 0-cost arrow from the start node to all tasks with no prerequisites, and a 0-cost arrow from all nodes which *aren't* prerequisites to anything else to the end node. Furthermore, the `start` and `end` nodes themselves are just book-keeping devices, they themselves shouldn't correspond to tasks which take any time to complete.

Topological sorting doesn't find it for you but is rather a form of pre-processing that allows you to find the critical path in a single pass. You use it to sort the nodes in such a way that the first node listed has no prerequisites and, when you come to a node in the sorted list, you are guaranteed that all prerequisite nodes have been processed. You process them by assigning a minimum start time for each task. The first node (the start node) in the sorted list has start time 0. When you get to a node for which all prerequisite nodes have been processed, the min start time of that node is

```
max({m_i + t_i })
```

where `i` ranges over all prerequisite nodes, `m_i` is the min start time for node `i` and `t_i` is the time it takes to do the task for node `i`. The point is that `m_i + t_i` is the minimum *finish* time for node `i` and you take the `max` of such things because all prerequisite tasks must be finished before a given task can be begu. The minimum start time of the end node is the length of the critical task.

Comment: Your question is essentially a duplicate (I should have realized that before responding). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864641/finding-minimum-completion-time-of-scheduled-tasks-with-topological-sort?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

create a directed graph G if a depends on b add a directed edge in G from b to a apply topological sort on G it lets say we stored it in a array called TOPO[],intialize time=H(0)
now run a loop over TOPO array starting from the second element.

**check if TOPO[i] depends on TOPO[i-1] if it is so we have to perform them one after the other so add their task times**

```
                time=time+H(i)
```

**if TOPO[i] does not dependent on TOPo[i-1] then we can perform them together so take a maximum of thier task times**

```
                time=max(time,H(i))
```

after the end of the loop variable **time** will have your answer

"
do this for every component separately and take the maximum of all